# Как поменять местами символы на Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка с цифрами надо поменять цифры местами на
пример строка:  3245
на выходе должно получиться : 2354; Кто подскажет, как это можно реализовать на JS?

Comment: Обычным циклом: `for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) r += s[i + 1] + s[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### вариант 1

Делаем цикл через исходную строку с шагом через один символ. Таким образом индекс будет проходить по парам символов исходной строки. И в теле цикла составляем новую строку, добавляя каждый раз пары символов в обратном порядке:

```js
let s = "3245";
let res = "";

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2){
  res += s[i+1] + s[i];
}
console.log(res);
```

### вариант 2

```js
console.log("3245".match(/(..?)/g).reduce((p,c)=>{
  p += c[1]+c[0];
  return p;
}, ""));
```

Comment: а если будет нечетное количество символов в строке?

Comment: @Grundy для нечтных можно res += (s[i+1] || '') + s[i]; (хотя смотря по условию конечно, автор не уточнил что делать в такой ситуации).

Comment: @Grundy у автора явно четные количества

Comment: Спасибо вам большое все примеры хороши, но мне больше понравилась регулярка.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с помощью метода [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): выделяем два символа в группы, и меняем их местами

```js
console.log("3245".replace(/(.)(.)?/g, "$2$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let s = "1234";
    let n = "";
    for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
     if((i % 2) != 0){
           n += s[i] + s[i-1];
        }
    }
    console.log(n);
```

Если количество символов нечетное, последний символ игнорируется.